How can we open the ngx-jira-issue-collector in a new tab instead of displaying it in a modal
I am using the ngx-jira-issue-collector package in my Angular application.
https://github.com/CatalystOne/ngx-jira-issue-collector

TS
config: CollectorOptions = {
  baseUrl: 'https://jira.myorg.com',
  collectorId: 'coll123',
  fieldValues: {
    summary: 'Title of ticket'
  },
  fieldValuesFn: () => {
    return {
      description: 'Textarea for in-depth description'
    };
  }
};

HTML
<div>
  <button (click)="collector.showDialog()">Click me!</button>
  <ngx-jira-issue-collector [configuration]="config" #collector></ngx-jira-issue-collector>
</div>

The Jira Issue Collector is displaying and functioning correctly. Now, I need to configure it to open in a new tab.
My Approach:
I am using the direct link obtained by inspecting the modal, specifically:
https://jira.gfk.com/rest/collectors/1.0/template/form/coll123?os_authType=none

It is opening the modal contents in a new tab. However, I am having trouble auto-populating the fields like email, description, etc, and the Issue Collector’s close button is not responsive.
Is this the correct approach, or is there a better way to handle it? Any assistance would be appreciated.
